# Cannot find mysql.sock Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, compiled, mysql.sock

I have compiled MySQL 5.5.27 on Snow Leopard OSX. Which is working good and mysql.sock is created where it is expected. Same binaries are used on Lion OSX, it works there too and also mysql.sock is created at desired location.

**BUT Only in Mountain Lion i cannot find the mysql.sock** at desired location. mysqld (MySQL Server) is working fine, I can create databases, etc. Everything is working fine, just cant find the mysql.sock.

```
my-pc:~ user$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep mysql.sock
socket           /usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Note : This output is displayed for all OSX.

Any help ? Thanks in advance.
Jigar.

Comment: do you have a "socket" entry in your my.cnf?

Comment: Yes. Entry is present. Path is same as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is already present, its a **socket** file. Don't know why the Finder can't display it. Use `ls -lha /usr/local/mysql/tmp` command to confirm it.